# Easiest way to share files between Ubuntu and Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, file-sharing

What is the easiest way to share files between two machines running on Ubuntu and Windows 7 machine?

I tried setting up SAMBA. It is way too difficult and didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on the Windows machine.

To install SSH on Linux you can do something like: `aptitude install openssh`

SAMBA is *too* complicated.

And if you're feeling especially lazy, install [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/) server on the Windows machine. Then you can use vnc on the Linux box to view the Windows desktop. From there, you can open a WinSCP session back to Linux. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Running Samba on the Ubuntu machine makes sharing the files easy.  Just mount the drive from Windows 7.  Windows shares can be mounted on the Ubuntu machine using smbfs.

Answer (score 0):

I use SFTP. It is very easy:

1. Install SSH server on your Linux machine (I usually select to install it during the system installation time, but it is easy to add later too, just run `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`).
2. Install any compatible client on your Windows system (I use FileZilla).
3. Enter your Linux system IP address, user name and password in the client to get access to your Linux system files.

No or almost no configuration required on any of the sides.